# Variables of Dryden Wind Model

Tags: aerodynamics, commercial-aviation, wind, turbulence, aerospace

How to determine the turbulence intensities (σu, σv, σw), scale lengths (Lu, Lv, Lw) & Angular frequency (ω0) in the given Dryden wind model to generate wind speeds (u_w, v_w, w_w) of civil jet transport aircraft that experiencing various levels of turbulence?
[image: Dryden model]